# Creating a column in dataset for later filter use (mysql)

Tags: mysql, case

I have a date column (format: 14.05.2018) and a count of sales. I would like to create an extra column that from the current date perspective flags fields that are +/-6 days from today. The following query does not work quite well, the column is empty

```
select `Date`, `Sales`,
(CASE 
    when DAY(CURRENT_DATE())-6 <= DAY(`Date`)
            AND DAY(CURRENT_DATE())-6 >=  DAY(`Date`) then '1'
    when DAY(CURRENT_DATE())-6 > DAY(`Date`)
            AND DAY(CURRENT_DATE())-6 < DAY(`Date`) then '0'
 end as Flag)
from sales;
```

[image]

Comment: can you please provides sample data  see [mre]

Comment: @nbk I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Data should obly be posted as text or ddl, that makes the live easier for all of us

Basically you query can be reduced to an If clause, as seen below, but as i tested it again, i noticed, mysql doesn't like you date format so it has to be converted to a date, so that the code can properly work.

**Schema (MySQL v5.6)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
  `Date` VARCHAR(10),
  `Sales` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO sales
  (`Date`, `Sales`)
VALUES
  ('14.05.2018', '8046'),
  ('11.02.2020', '4564'),
  ('25.07.2018', '6648'),
  ('25.08.2020', '7785'),
  ('01.09.2020', '8788'),
  ('30.04.2018', '4655'),
  ('22.09.2019', '6867'),
  ('09.12.2016', '6868'),
  ('26.10.2018', '6785'),
  ('01.09.2020', '7456'),
  ('12.12.2018', '7456');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select `Date`, `Sales`,
IF(CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY <= STR_TO_DATE(`Date`,'%d.%c.%Y')
            AND CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 6 DAY >=  STR_TO_DATE(`Date`,'%d.%c.%Y'),1,0) flag
from sales;

| Date       | Sales | flag |
| ---------- | ----- | ---- |
| 14.05.2018 | 8046  | 0    |
| 11.02.2020 | 4564  | 0    |
| 25.07.2018 | 6648  | 0    |
| 25.08.2020 | 7785  | 0    |
| 01.09.2020 | 8788  | 1    |
| 30.04.2018 | 4655  | 0    |
| 22.09.2019 | 6867  | 0    |
| 09.12.2016 | 6868  | 0    |
| 26.10.2018 | 6785  | 0    |
| 01.09.2020 | 7456  | 1    |
| 12.12.2018 | 7456  | 0    |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4yPorU6k3SjQ5nmhgi1wGo/19)

Comment: Thanks @nbk! Is there an alternative for Interval 6 day? it doesn't seem to recognize it

Comment: no the problem was you date format, mysql scrables it massivly, i edited my answer, and converted it to date, now it works

Answer (score 0):

> I have a date column (format: 14.05.2018) ...

I would suggest not.

**Dates** *have no format*.
Not one that you or I need to worry about, anyway.  Leave it to the IEEE engineers.

You have a **Char** column that *just happens* to contain some text that you or I would interpret as a **Date**.  As you've discovered, it's mighty difficult (and slow) to do "Date" stuff on things that aren't **Dates**.  All those calls to str_to_date mean your query will table-scan, because it doesn't know any better way to work out what values you're trying to filter on.
Using the correct Data Types makes your queries easier to read and allows the Database to use indexes on those fields (quicker!)

```
select `Date`, `Sales`,
IF ( CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY <= STR_TO_DATE(`Date`,'%d.%c.%Y')
   AND CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 6 DAY >=  STR_TO_DATE(`Date`,'%d.%c.%Y') 
, 1, 0 ) flag
from sales;
```

becomes

```
select `Date`, `Sales`,
IF ( CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY <= `Date` 
   AND CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 6 DAY >=  `Date` 
, 1, 0 ) flag
from sales;
```

or, possibly (untested) even:

```
select `Date`, `Sales`,
IF ( `Date` BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY 
   AND CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 6 DAY 
   , 1, 0 ) flag
from sales;
```

Not that you should be using `Date` as a field name anyway - *always* avoid using Reserved Words as identifiers.  You can all but guarantee you'll come across some case where it trips you up.

> I would like to create an extra column that from the current date perspective flags fields that are +/-6 days from today.

Don't store data that can (and should) be derived.
If you store this "flag" as a field, then you have to update each and every record each and every day to reflect the changing calendar.

If you're lucky enough to have a version of MySQL that supports virtual columns (5.7+), use one of those to calculate the value "on the fly" or, failing that, create a View to work it out.